# Console multiple lines with countdown timer

Tags: c#, console

Is having multiple real-time counting down in C# console possible? I have seen solutions setting cursor for 1 countdown but it's not working for multiple lines.

Is something like this with real-time countdown possible for a console?

```
MEAL A: SERVED (0 sec)
MEAL B: PREPARING (14 sec)
MEAL C: PREPARING (30 sec)
```

Comment: You should be able to fiddle around with the cursor, but in my experience it can be problematic if some other component wants to use the console, or you want to pipe the console output to file. I usually assume console programs are run from something else, so user feedback like this is less important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Console.SetCursorPosition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-6.0) to do this.

For example (compilable console app):

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MEAL A: <status>");
        Console.WriteLine("MEAL B: <status>");
        Console.WriteLine("MEAL C: <status>");

        int statusOffset = 8;
        int topRow = Console.CursorTop - 3;

        int mealEtaA = 10;
        int mealEtaB = 20;
        int mealEtaC = 30;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            if (mealEtaA > 0)
                --mealEtaA;

            if (mealEtaB > 0)
                --mealEtaB;

            if (mealEtaC > 0)
                --mealEtaC;

            Console.SetCursorPosition(statusOffset, topRow);
            Console.Write(status(mealEtaA));

            Console.SetCursorPosition(statusOffset, topRow+1);
            Console.Write(status(mealEtaB));

            Console.SetCursorPosition(statusOffset, topRow+2);
            Console.Write(status(mealEtaC));
        }
    }

    static string status(int eta)
    {
        // Note: Status string contains enough spaces at the end to overwrite any previous status.
        return eta <= 0 ? "SERVED       " : $"PREPARING {eta}  ";
    }
}
```